# MySQL order by Facebook friends

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need a way to order a list of rows and place the user's Facebook friends first.

Is there any way I can do it? Which approach should I follow?

I have never worked with Facebook Connect, so this is just a hypothetic question, because I'll be working with it soon.

Should I just get the Facebook friend list EVERY time a user search (and the list will be generated). Then in my table, I'll save every user's facebook_uid?

But how will I order it so Facebook friends is first, and "strangers" will be shown afterwards?

My table could for example look like this:

```
id - facebook_uid - text
1  - 1111111      - lorem ipsum.....
2  - 2222222      - something else....
3  - 3333333      - third!!!
```

So if for example 1111111 and 3333333 are friends of mine, the returned ID's would be (in the right order): 1,3,2.

How do I order that in SQL (or PHP logic)?

Comment: Did you already parse the list in your database (as the tags suggests) or do you want to query the API that way?

Comment: I have updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed Robin's approach with two arrays.

First, I load the Facebook friend list (json) from Graph. I then loop through it, creating an array with ONLY the friend IDs. That way, I could just use in_array to check if a specific ID was a friend.

```
<?php
function get_facebook_friends(){
    $friends = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=XXXXXX"));
    $friendArray = array();

    foreach($friends->data as $friend){
        $friendArray[] = $friend->id;
    }

    return $friendArray;
}

function is_facebook_friend($friends, $facebook_uid){   
    return in_array($facebook_uid, $friends);
}

//Do your query stuff...

$friends = get_facebook_friends();
$is_friends = array();
$not_friends = array();

foreach ($rows as $row){
    if(is_facebook_friend($friends, $row->facebook_uid)){ //Is friend
        $is_friends[] = $row;
    }else{
        $not_friends[] = $row;          
    }
}

$rows = array_merge($is_friends, $not_friends);

//Do normal loop here
?>
```

It is very efficient and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook graph can use [fql](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/). Although it's based on SQL, it has some limits such as missing `NOT IN()` and stuff. By running all of the taken `facebook_id`s through the table [`friend`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/), you could find out if they are friends through the query.

This assumes you store all of their ids. Lets say you search, and get 10 results. Run all of these id's through the `friend`-table like:

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() AND uid2 IN ({$search_user_1}, {$search_user_1}, ...)
```

The uid2's returned are obviously friends of given person.

**UPDATE:**

I doubt fql can handle `UNION` and `subqueries` as needed for this. But my solution still remians the same.

Extract the rows, run the fql through Facebook's api and compare matches. If they match, you can put those in the array `$friends`, else `$not_friends` and then `$users = array_merge($friends, $not_friends)` and they get sorted. Use your imagination.

This, or run a fql first to get current users friends, and then add them to your own database in an other table each visiting day/hour/page. Then simply run a `JOIN` to check if they're friends or not.

Comment: Hi Robin, used your approach. See above post I made with final code :)

Answer (score 0):

> So if for example 1111111 and 3333333 are friends of mine, the returned ID's would be (in the right order): 1,3,2.
>
> How do I order that in SQL (or PHP logic)?

I’d say this should be enough (in MySQL):

```
… ORDER BY IF(facebook_uid IN (1111111,3333333), 1, 0) DESC
```

This results in a “sort value” of 1 if the facebook_uid of the record is in the given list, and 0 otherwise. Sorting it DESCending makes the 1 values come before the 0 values.

Inserting the actuall list of comma-separated friend ids into the IN operator’s brackets should be no big deal, for example if you have them as an array you can just implode them with a comma as separator.